# Spring Boot with MVC application using H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, h2

I am pretty new using embedded databases, and using Spring MVC also. I have made spring boot applications and used h2 database but in separate projects, and I am having trouble putting the two together.

My most recent problem is in the `index.jsp` page I am using to display a list of candidate constituencies for the user to choose. I have overcome creating a connection, however I keep receiving the error: `"Table "CANDIDATES" not found; SQL statement: SELECT DISTINCT CONSTITUENCY FROM candidates ORDER BY CONSTITUENCY [42102-187]"`.

I know the table is there, but I am unsure if I have it set up in the right place in my project architecture. I created a folder called SQL (in src, then main) and placed a `data.sql` and `schema.sql` fill inside this

```
>ELECTION2016
 >src/main/java
 >src/main/resources
 >src/test/java
 >JRE System Library
 >Maven Dependencies
 >Apache Tomcat v8.0
 v src
  v main
   >webapp
   v SQL
    >data.sql
    >schema.sql
  >test   
 >target
 >pom.xml
```

Basically I am unsure if I have placed the sql files in the right place!

My `index.jsp` page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Election 2016</title>
</head>
<body BGCOLOR=#FFE5B4>

 <%
    try {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT CONSTITUENCY FROM candidates ORDER BY CONSTITUENCY");
    %>
    <h2>Choose constituency</h2>
    <form name="constituencyform" action="display.jsp" method="post">
    <select name="constituency">
    <%
        while (rs.next()) {
            %><option><%=rs.getString(1)%></option><%
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    %>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
    <%
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        %><%= ex.getMessage() %><%
    }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot `DataSourceInitializer` expects `schema.sql` and `data.sql` in **src/main/resources** folder. It is scripts default location. 

Firsl of all move **SQL** folder to the resources and define custom location using following properties

```
spring.datasource.schema=classpath*:sql/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath*:sql/data.sql
```

Or just move scripts to the default location.